# How to add canonical URL to example.com/blog?

Tags: wordpress, seo, canonical-link, yoast

How to add canonical URL to `example.com/blog`?

I am using Yoast plugin. For the other pages I can see an option to mark canonical URL, but for `example.com/blog` that lists all blog posts there is no physical page. So not able to mark canonical URL using Yoast plugin.

Comment: Why would you need to add a canonical URL to a blog page? But it seems that Yoast SEO links them weirdly when it comes to blog pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code into your function.php file

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'new_rel_canonical' );

function new_rel_canonical() {
 if ( !is_singular() )
      return;

  global $wp_the_query;
  if ( !$id = $wp_the_query->get_queried_object_id() )
      return;

  $link = get_permalink( $id );
  $link = str_replace( 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com', $link );
  echo "<link rel='canonical' href='$link' />\n";
  }
```

I think its work for you. check and let me know